# Selenium click not working on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I'm trying to click with selenium on Internet Explorer and it's not working. I have tried `element.click()`, `moveToElement(element).click().build().perform()`, `javascript` and nothing.

Actually, the click works sometimes. It's really unstable. I also tried wait until is clickable, `Thread.sleep` and, guess what, nothing changes.

I'm using `Selenium 3.4.0`, `IEDriverServer_x64_3.0.0`, `ie11` and `java`.

Comment: did you check the zoom level is 100%? you need to provide the HTML and actual error log to identify the issue.

Comment: @Bendram I did check the zoom level. I can't provide the HTML, cause the code is from my work, but it's really unstable. Sometimes the error is in one place, sometimes in other... But the thing is that selenium apparently clicks the element, but ie doesn't recognize and then the test continues. The error is because ie doesn't find the element that is supposed to be accessed after that first element has been clicked.

Comment: If you cannot post the actual source code, could you try and post a sanitized version of it?  All that we can do with the current description is a guess and check of standard troubleshooting procedures.

Comment: One thing you can do is to WAIT for the element and also move by offset.

Comment: seleniumActions.MoveToElement(PageObject).MoveByOffset(xOffset, yOffset).Click().Build().Perform();

Comment: @Hashim77 It didn't work. :(

Comment: Well, did you have the right offset? And did you wait for the element to be displayed?

Comment: @Hashim77 Yes: 
 `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));     action.moveToElement(element).moveByOffset(element.getLocation().getX(), element.getLocation().getY()).click().build().perform();`  and also: `if(element.isDisplayed()){  action.moveToElement(element).moveByOffset(element.getLocation().getX(), element.getLocation().getY()).click().build().perform();  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this solution somewhere and it worked for me:

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator)) 
element.sendKeys("");
element.click();`

I don't understand what `element.sendKeys("")` actually does, but it's ok.