# click() is not working in IE11 driver using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Code:

```
webBrowser = webdriver.Ie(r'C:\Users\XYZ\WebDriver\IEDriverServer.exe')
webBrowser.get(URL)
webBrowser.implicitly_wait(15)
webBrowser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="number_id"]').send_keys('12345')
webBrowser.find_element_by_id("Submit").click()
applicationData = [td.text for td in webBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsRow"]')]
```

click() is working in Chrome, FF but not in IE11. Except for click() rest of the script is working in IE11.

How to make it work in IE11.

NOTE: Using IE11-32 bit driver

Comment: Check out these links -> [first](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/webdriver-clicking-button-issue-in-ie-11), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653800/selenium-click-not-working-on-internet-explorer-11). Hopefully they will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Open Display settings in Windows

Select "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" and set to 100%.

After above steps, Click() method worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.